# How to fix " Casting Exception for User given String to Date conversion"

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to get the user input for: `float salary`, `string input` of `DateTime doj`, accept them and Display them on Console.

- With `DateTime doj`, it shows Type casting error while accept.
- If declared as `string doj`, the output is correct.

For conversion from `string` to `Datetime`, I tried using `Parse, Tryparse,tryparseexact`.

Code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Enter your salary");
salary = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("enter your date of joining in dd/mm/yyyy");
input = Console.ReadLine();
doj=DateTime.Parse("input")
/*
doj=Convert.toDatetime("Console.Readline()")
*/
```

Comment: Please format your question to make it easier to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you format the post please, it is hardly readable currently. See [ask]

Comment: `doj =DateTime.Parse( "input");` doesn't parse the input variable but the string "input"

Comment: Thanks Stefan. doj =DateTime.Parse( input)  or doj = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); gives same error  "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error

Comment: Thank you Sean and Xiawi.Will look into it. Have edited

Answer (score 0):

Targaryen

If your assignment is to convert a string that contains a specific date format to a DateTime object than you should use one of these two methods:

[DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.6#remarks)

Or

[DateTime.TryParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.6)

Since you state you tried both, I guessing you did not format them correctly.

Here what I see wrong with what you posted so far.

Your sample is showing parameters surrounded by quotes.  As pointed out by Stefan this is not correct.

```
doj=DateTime.Parse("input")
doj=Convert.toDatetime("Console.Readline()")
```

You should review the above reference documentation on the command usage.   Note they contain examples on how to use the command.

You also mention to Stefan that the following code did not work.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The cause might be due to the fact you are looking for just the date to be inputted but the format you have listed also is looking for time information.  If you are just looking for date information, only specify a format pattern that includes date elements only.

As reference, codes use as date and time specifiers are listed here:

[Date And Time format in C Sharp](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Good Luck.

Comment: Hello Mentat, thanks for your detailed reply. Yes, I have noted your points and have changed accordingly.                                           doj = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);   Have given this and now I am able to get output. The thing is even if i input 29/05/2019(29 May,2019), it shows 05/29/19. Just to ask, is this related to the date format on my system?(since I saw few posts on internet)

Comment: The date is stored internally as a numeric value.  If you are displaying the date without any format options and your default culture is “en-us”, then default date format is: mm/dd/yyyy.
More information on standard date and time format strings can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings